# visual studio 2015: suppress error in .net mvc application in production?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

anytime there's an error, it shows the stack trace, is there a way to suppress this when the .net mvc application is deployed in production? I googled and searched through SO but couldn't find an option in web.config that I could turn on to suppress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the the attribute to `debug=false`.

Go to Web.config, under `<system.web>` change it to `<compilation debug="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tag in webconfig:

```
<customErrors mode="on"/>
```